# Trying to Add a Footnote on the last Page of an Excel File using a loop

Tags: vba, loops

I'm currently working on an invoice which could span multiple pages and I want the Signature to appear near the bottom of the last page of the invoice.

My idea:

1. If the invoice is only one page long I would like to place the signature on `Row 39`.
2. If there is data in `Row 39`,then Place the Footnote at the end of the next page which is `Row 86` (add 47 rows).
3. Continue doing that until an empty row is found. So if `Row 86` has Data add another `47 Rows` and place the footer in `Row 133`.

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to get the loop to work, I know how to get a loop to work when you're using a count Do `while i >` (insert amount here) **but I don't know how to do it until it finds an empty row**.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it exactly that way.  Start with the last used row (plus one), then use a loop to find the next appropriate row after that.

```
lastRow = activesheet.usedrange.rows.count + 1
sigRow = 39
while sigRow < lastRow
    sigRow = sigRow + 47
    wend

activesheet.cells(sigRow, c) = signature
```

Now, this is pseudocode, so you will need to adapt it to your specific use.  For instance, you have to define the signature, and tell it what column to put it in (c is the placeholder).  You may want to explicitly name the worksheet instead of just using activesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up Solving it

Public Sub Signature()

```
Dim Signature_Line As String
Dim Signature_Labels As String
Dim Signed As Integer
Dim Signature_Row As Integer

Signature_Line = "  _________________________     _________________________     ______________________________"
Signature_Labels = "                          Name                                                  Date                                                   Signature"

Signed = 0
Signature_Row = 39

Do Until Signed = 1

If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Signature_Row - 1)) = True Then
ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Signature_Row).Value = Signature_Line
ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Signature_Row + 1).Value = Signature_Labels
Signed = Signed + 1

Else

Signature_Row = Signature_Row + 47
End If

Loop


End Sub
```